# Is there any way to add caption for pheatmap in r?

Tags: r, caption, pheatmap

How can I add caption for my picture in pheatmap?
I could not find any similar arguments in package.

```
pheatmap(x)
```

Comment: You can use `main` to add a title - `pheatmap(x, main = 'title')` but can't find a way to add a caption below the heat map.